# html form does not send values to php

Tags: php, html, function, file, post

Im having trouble getting $first and $second and $operation to be sent through to php and i dont know what im doing wrong

```
<form action="calculator.php" method="post">
<fieldset>

<p> Enter First Number <input type = "text" name = "first"><br></p>
<p> Enter Second Numer <input type = "text" name = "second"><br></p>
<p>Which would you like to do ?
<select name="operation">
<option value="Addition">Addition</option>
<option value="Subtraction">Subtraction</option>
<option value="Multiplication">Multiplication</option>
<option value="Division">Division</option>
<option value="Min">MIN</option>
<option value="Max">MAX</option>
</select>
<input type = "submit" value = "Calculate"/>
<input type = "reset" value = "Clear, and try again" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

my php

```
 $first = $_POST['first'];
 $second = $_POST['second'];
 $operation = $_POST['operation'];
```

also what would be a quick and easy way to add a log file that writes $first $second $operation and $result in a file named "calculating.dat" in this format  :  :  :

The calculating.php must also keep a running log of the requests to the webapp in a file named calcFunctionsLog.dat.  :::

Comment: Did you check if you reach `calculator.php` Do an echo in an if(isset($_POST['first']) Can you provide some more code?

Comment: what else should i provide?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['first'] gives me more errors "unexpected if" ad breaks the code

Comment: You say "more errors" what errors did you have so far? The unexpected if error sounds weird. Can you show your php file?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UzGY6pP8 thats link to the php

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4sZmkALB thats link to the include() functions file

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ADugd8xC thats link to my html form

Comment: also how to make a log file containing all user input $first $second $operation $result

Comment: please check my reply

Answer (score 0):

I found some errors in your code. You have  a typo in the function `getProd` You write "$firsr" instead of "$first". And I am not sure why you have html and body tags in the `calculator.php` you do not close it at all and it has no function or am I wrong?

Also remove the `isnumeric` in your functions php file. They have no use.

This is your fixed part for the logging. if you also want to output the `$result` you have to make a new variable $result at the top and update it after the calculation is done (in your if's)

```
$logFile = 'calculating.dat';
$logFile = fopen("calculating.dat", "a");
$log = $first.$second.$operation;
fwrite($logFile, $log);
$newLog = $log."\n";
fwrite($logFile, $newLog);
fclose($logFile);
```

here the pastes of the edited files:

https://pastebin.com/aKincTnL

https://pastebin.com/adJXtyH8

Comment: i still cant figure out why $first $second and $operation are not showing up

Comment: why do both my if statement error messages for non numeric entry and empty input field still show up no matter what is entered in as a value

Comment: Where do they not show up. Where do you expect it? When I use this code and with the few changes I described it works. It logs first second and operation to calculating.dat

Comment: I edited my answer and added pastebin links. maybe that helps? let me know

Comment: the logging works. i need it to display error message when the if statement is true with the back link and if none of the if statements are true to display the result of the two number

Comment: Check this: https://pastebin.com/vDEGjGMb You try to make a valdiation of the input but you missed that it would still try to calculate with the inputs even if it failed the validation. So with proper if clauses it will work I guess?

Comment: That's worked now for it to display $result that is sent back from function cause now that won't display